# How to manage django admin for country section with same back and frontend listing page

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I am new in Django. I am creating a app `countries` which will have listing page in both frontend and backend. I have manage frontend by writing code in root urls.py

```
path('countries/', include(('countries.urls', 'countries'), namespace = 'countries'))
```

And in countries/urls.py

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

in `models.py` I write country model for frontend and In `views.py` write `index` function for frontend.
This is my models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    iso_code    = models.CharField(max_length=2, unique=True)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_featured = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'countries'
```

And in views.py I write

```
def index(request):
    countries = Country.objects.all().order_by('id')
    context = {
        "countries" : countries
    }
    return render(request, 'countries/index.html', context)
```

If I run http://127.0.0.1:8000/countries/ then it will load country listing page in frontend.
Now, I want http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/countries/ to see backend listing page with custom admin template.
Please help me if someone know 
If I add `path('admin/countries/', include(('countries.urls', 'countries'), namespace = 'countries')),` in urls.py then http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/countries/ is also take same template page and does not show admin template.

Comment: where is your admin.py??

Comment: I dont know what to write in admin.py. Now this file is blank.

Comment: read docs(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/), and try to create admin page. For this specific thing you will need just a couple of lines, try to figure it out. Also django's default admin page template is pretty good, don't bother trying to implement custom template.

Comment: If I write path('admin/countries/', include(('countries.urls', 'countries'), namespace = 'countries')), in countries/urls.py then it give same listing page

Comment: `path('admin/', admin.site.urls),` something like this depending how you import admin in your urls.py

Answer (score 0):

**In the admin.py of your `countries` app, do this:**

Although note that this is for django 2.x. You didn't specifiy your version, but django 1.x isn't much different from the following example. I just skimmed 1.11 quick, and the 2 attributes I checked in the options section were the same [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options) If you get a bug, change to the version you need, and fix the attribute.

```
from .models import Country
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(Country)
class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['iso_code', 'name', 'is_featured']
    list_editable = ['name']  # Add more here if you want to edit them inline.
    list_filter = ['iso_code']  # add more to be able to filter your model
    list_per_page = 10  # paginates the amount that show up per page
    search_fields = ['name', 'iso_code']  # field names searched
```